# Crm 2011 many to many Relationship

Tags: many-to-many, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I'm trying to create a N:N Relationship between the lead entity and a custom entity(lets name it system).
This works without problem.

If I'm trying to add 'system' records to lead it does not work,
I'm also not getting any error or info. It just don't adds the record.

If I'm trying to do the same on my custom entity(system) i can add any Lead i want.

is there any restriction on lead that prevents this?

**edit**
looks like its only related to lead other entities work. Any many to many relationships on lead do not work. i have deactivated all update and associate plugins but still no help.

and on other CRm it did work :-(

Comment: In the relationship how have you set the display options?

Comment: display options are 'Use Plural Name' in both